# How to set a function as an alias in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

| id | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03.06.2023 | 20000 |
| 1 | 04.06.2023 | 30000 |
| 1 | 05.06.2023 | 40000 |

And I need to receive next format table:

| date | 03.06.2023 | 04.06.2023 | 05.06.2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20000 | 30000 | 40000 |

I use next query:

```
select t.id as date,
       max(case when t.d = current_date - 2 then t.a end) "03.06.2023",
       max(case when t.d = current_date - 1 then t.a end) "04.06.2023",
       max(case when t.d = current_date then t.a end) "05.06.2023"
from t
group by t.id
```

But I need to reload column names every day on a new current date, how can I do this?

Comment: You can use _dynamic SQL_ to get updated column names each day.

Answer (score 0):

*Comment posted as an answer to work around the length limit and formatting limitations.*

[`execute format()` in a PL/pgSQL block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), or [`crosstab`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) can both achieve this, both get ugly. You're effectively facing the limitation that forces structure names and types to be *known* at call time. Current date keeps changing and needs to be freshly checked, so you could say "call time isn't known at call time".

You can also consider listing dates in one column (today, yesterday, the day before that), then the `max(t.a)` for those

```sql
select t.id as date, 
       t.d, 
       max(t.a) 
from t 
where t.d>=(current_date-2) 
group by t.id, 
         t.d;
```

Also, you're emulating [aggregate `filter` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES), as this:

```sql
max(case when t.d = current_date - 2 then t.a end)
```

is an old way of doing this:

```sql
max(t.a) filter (where t.d=current_date-2)
```